# Specify path to files

Tags: php, html

First of all, I'm totally new to PHP, so I'll need a bit more explanation. I'm trying to make a Multi-language site using PHP, the problem is; when I create a new folder like: `domain.tld/test/location` (location is new in this case), the language files which are located at `domain.tld/test`, are of course not imported. How can you clarify where these files NEED to be coming from?

**Script**

```
<?php
// include language configuration file based on selected language
echo realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
$lang = "en";
if(isset($_GET['lang'])){ 
    $lang = $_GET['lang']; 
} 
require_once("lang.".$lang.".php");
?>
```

Comment: According to the code you provided, the language files should be placed in the same folder as the file containing the code - otherwise, the folder should be provided in the require_once call

Comment: That's true! But if want to provide the parent-folder, how exactly do I find the path? I've like, tried it with path that are basically starting from my Harddrive, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Paths in php are like path in many languages. If you want to go backward, you add `../` before the path

```
require_once('../file/in/prev/dir');
```

I really suck at path, so whenever I have to make sure of one, I try it in my terminal. Maybe this can help you figure out where your file is.

However, I don't get why and how you need to do it this way... I mean, if you have one file for each language, why not doing it in HTML ? The main point of dealing with PHP is that you don't want to duplicate files, which is what you're doing.

You might be looking for Relational Database in which you'd have a table with generic content and another one with tranlated content. For example

Article :
|id| date |
|1 |8/8/08|

Translated Content :
|id| content |lang|
|1 | Hello   | en |
|2 | Bonjour | fr |

and intermediate table :
|article_id|content_id|
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../lang.' . $lang . '.php';
```

Alternatively you could load upfront for all your Php files see:

```
auto_prepend_file
```